# Angular2 page is not scrollable after async data is loaded

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I'm building a blog with Angular 2, and in the listing page I'm fetching the posts from firebase using Angularfire `FirebaseListObservable`. The problem is, after the posts are loaded, the page is not scrollable even though the listing exceeds the current visible window. Here's screenshot of the page. There's more posts which are not visible and the page is not scrollable.

[image]

The component.html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let post of posts | async"><h1>{{ post.title }}</h1></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: perhaps you have set `overflow: hidden` instead of `overflow: scroll`

Comment: I did not set any overflow rules, by default it should be scroll. But since you mention it,  I explicitly set `body{overflow: scroll}` with no avail. @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: If there is more content but it doesn't scroll I don't see how this would be related to Angular. I guess this requires a Plunker to reproduce to be able to diagnose the cause.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think I found the problem. The styling on selector component is set as `position:fixed` which is preventing the items to be scrolled. How do I remove that style? No luck targetting `:host`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I should know . Your question doesn't contain any information. I would need to see the HTML, the components involved and which element you want to apply the style.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer solved the problem by using `:host(selector){position: unset !important}`. Not sure if it's the best way to do so.
Thanks for your help, you did your best, my fault for not giving enough details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the styling on the component selector was set as position:fixed which was preventing the items to be scrolled. I fixed it by setting

```
:host(selector){
    position: unset !important;
}
```